# cannot post data to CakePHP 3 app from VB.Net WebRequest on https

Tags: vb.net, cakephp, https, cakephp-3.0, webrequest

Can we post data from VB.Net to CakePHP on https? using below code, it only display "GET" not "POST" response, so if use $this->request->getData(), will return empty array.

Note :

- post works on CakePHP 3 on http, or native php on https
- using VB.Net 2008 , target framework: 3.5
- using CakePHP 3.5.3
- Wamp Server 3.1.0 64bit
- Apache 2.4.27 - PHP 5.6.31

---

**VB.Net App code :**

```
'ByPass SSL Certificate Validation Checking
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = _
      Function(se As Object, _
      cert As System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate, _
      chain As System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain, _
      sslerror As System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors) True

    'Call web application/web service with HTTPS URL
    Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://localhost/testapp/test/")

    ' Set the Method property of the request to POST.  
    request.Method = "POST"

    ' Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.  
    Dim postData As String = "name=yos"
    Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)

    ' Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.  
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

    ' Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.  
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length

    ' Get the request stream.  
    Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()

    ' Write the data to the request stream.  
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)

    ' Close the Stream object.  
    dataStream.Close()

    ' Get the response.  
    Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()

    ' Display the status.  
    Console.WriteLine(CType(response, HttpWebResponse).StatusDescription)

    ' Get the stream containing content returned by the server.  
    dataStream = response.GetResponseStream()

    ' Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.  
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)

    ' Read the content.  
    Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()

    ' Display the content.  
    Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer)

    ' Clean up the streams.  
    reader.Close()
    dataStream.Close()
    response.Close()

    txtResponse.Text = responseFromServer

    'Restore SSL Certificate Validation Checking
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = Nothing
```

---

**CakePHP Code :**

*TestController.php*

```
class TestController extends AppController {
    public function index(){
        $this->autoRender = false;
        print_r($this->request->getMethod());
        print_r($this->request->getData());
    }
}
```

*AppController.php*

```
class AppController extends Controller
    {
        public function initialize()
        {
            parent::initialize();

            $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
            $this->loadComponent('Flash');
            $this->loadComponent('Security', ['blackHoleCallback' => 'forceSSL']);
        }

        public function beforeRender(Event $event)
        {
            if (!array_key_exists('_serialize', $this->viewVars) &&
                in_array($this->response->type(), ['application/json', 'application/xml'])
            ) {
                $this->set('_serialize', true);
            }
        }

        public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
        {
            $this->Security->requireSecure();
        }

        public function forceSSL()
        {
            return $this->redirect('https://' . env('SERVER_NAME') . $this->request->here());
        }
    }
```

---

**Server Response**

```
GET //should be POST
Array() //should be Array([name] => yos)
```